# How to setup Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31) in Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, drivers

How to install this WiFi adapter in Arch Linux: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)?

Please help as I can't connect to wireless right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [`linux-firmware`](https://archlinux.org/packages/core/any/linux-firmware/) from core repository. Then:

```
sudo modprobe -rv ath10k_pci 
sudo modprobe -v ath10k_pci
```